# How to remap default vim text-object keys to different keys like ' to n

Tags: key-bindings, custom-text-object

I use `ci'`, `va"` pretty often, I would like to map text-object keys like `"` `'` to more accessible keys like `m`, `n` since writing `cin`, `vam` is much easier than `ci'` `va"`.

I tried the following

```
vmap am a"
vmap im i"

omap am a"
omap im i"

vmap an a'
vmap in i'

omap an a'
omap in i'
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Wait! Your keybindings _do_ work for me. Are you sure your vim instance has taken the keybindings? What does `:map am` outputs?

Comment: @kadekai It works when I only map one key like `:omap am a"` but for some reason it doesn't work when I map both `m` and `n`. I guess I need to read more manual pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xnoremap im :<C-u>normal! T"vt"<CR>
onoremap im :normal vi"<CR>
xnoremap in :<C-u>normal! T'vt'<CR>
onoremap in :normal vi'<CR>
```